# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am learning  Paging in MVC
in Index View I have Search Button which should display result Paged Wise

Index Method in Home Controller ...

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search ,int? Page)
 {
     if (searchBy == "Gender")
     {
         return View(db.Employees.Where(x => x.Gender == search || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(Page??1,3)) ;
     }
     else
     {
         return View(db.Employees.Where(x => x.FUllName == search || search == null).ToList());
     }
 }
```

and Index View

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc; 

@model IPagedList<_SearchDemo.Models.Employee>

    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <b>SearchBy</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Name", true)       
            <text>Name</text>
            @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Gender") <text>Gender</text>
            <br />
            @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="search" />
        }
    </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().FUllName)
            </th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FUllName)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

On reloading Index page it gives error ...

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`, but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1

Comment: Why don't you take a close look at the error message, then look at the two `return View...` lines and I bet you can figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you when you've done everything you can do on your own, not as your first stop the moment you get some error. This error in particular is one of the few that is *very* specific about what the problem is, and I'm sure you could have easily figured it out on your own, had you taken a few moments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your code is reaching the `else` part of your Action which is only returning a `List<T>` of Employees when your view is expecting a `PagedList<T>` of Employees.

You can either create and return a new View which accepts `List<T>` of Employees or change your code to return `.ToPagedList`